# Android menu buttons visibility

Tags: android, android-actionbar, show-hide, menuitem

I have a button in my actionbar that hides all the buttons and should show another three but it shows only two of them. The number of items is 7. The buttons's (that have to be showed) showAsAction is ifRoom.

Here is how I hide/unhide my buttons:

```
private void hideUnhideActionButtons(boolean hide) {
    MenuItem item;
    Log.d("Item numbers", Integer.toString(audioMenu.size()));
    for(int i = 0; i < audioMenu.size(); ++i ) {
        if(i < 4)
            audioMenu.getItem(i).setVisible(!hide);
        else
            audioMenu.getItem(i).setVisible(hide);
    }   
    audioMenu.getItem(6).setVisible(true);
}
```

Here is where I call this method:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch(id) {                
        case R.id.action_camera:
            ...
            return true;

        case R.id.action_audio:
            hideUnhideActionButtons(true);

            return true;

        case R.id.action_record:
            ...
            return true;

        case R.id.action_play:
                            ...

            return true;

        case R.id.action_return:
            hideUnhideActionButtons(false);

            return true;

        case R.id.action_delete:
            ...
            return true;

        case R.id.action_save: 
            ...
                            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

My XML:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.victwo.NewNoteActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_save"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_save"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@+string/action_save"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_remove"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@+string/action_delete"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_camera"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@+string/action_camera"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_audio"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_volume_on"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@+string/action_record"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_record"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_mic"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@+string/action_record"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_play"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_play"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@+string/action_play"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_return"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_back"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@+string/action_return"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>


</menu>
```

Can anybody tell me what is the problem?

Comment: can you be more relevant please ! past much more code !

Comment: why can't you access `MenuItem` by their `id`'s, instead of `indexes` ?

Comment: Using something like : `menu.findItem(R.id.my_menu_id)`, thus you will `setVisible()` to `true` or `false` easily.

Comment: I access them by id in the onOptionsItemSelected() method
but I couldn't find how to do this outside this method with loop. If I don't hide the icons in loop the code will become redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a reference to your menu, which is `audioMenu`. So you can access to your menu items using `findItem` method and giving their `id`'s instead of `indexes`.

Example :

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch(id) {                
        case R.id.action_camera:
            ...
            return true;

        case R.id.action_audio:
            //hide
            actionMode.findItem(R.id.id_1).setVisible(false);
            actionMode.findItem(R.id.id_2).setVisible(false);
            //show
            actionMode.findItem(R.id.id_3).setVisible(true);
            actionMode.findItem(R.id.id_4).setVisible(true);
            return true;

        case R.id.action_record:
            ...
            return true;

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```